# Max OSX: I have a windows that opens and then quickly closes before I can see it. How can I catch it?

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion

I have a window that open on Mountain Lion, then closes almost immediately, about once every 3 hours. I don't know what is says as I don't have time to read it, but I can tell that there are 3-5 lines of text and a yellow "warning" symbol. I want to stop it from appearing (preferably by fixing whatever I am being warned about)

a) Has anyone had this problem before that might know what it is?

b) Are there any tools or information I can use to make it easier to find the source myself? Maybe something that logs whenever a window opens or closes, along with some metadata like the title or the window or its root cause? Or maybe something that prevents windows from closing themselves, temporarily forcing me to close all windows manually?

Comment: Check *Console.app* and look at all messages around the time you see the alert.

Comment: You could also try running `sudo opensnoop` or `sudo execsnoop`.

Comment: @LauriRanta I've never used those tools. execsnoop I think I can figure out but opensnoop I'm not sure what to look for.

Comment: @Drew I thought it might include some image files or other files related to the application that displays the window.

Comment: I've seen this happen with firewall queries that shouldn't disappear but do.